# What linear programming problem gives the solution to this matrix game problem?

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory

So this game has the following matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1       &-1& -2  \\
    -1       & 2 & -1  \\
    -2       & -1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$
So if I know correctly I should consider the following problem:

$$\max e^Tu$$
$$Au \leq  e$$
$$u\geq 0$$

Now my problem is that I'm not sure about what $e$ is it the 3-dimensional vector with 1 entries in my case? 
The other thing I'm not sure about if this is even solveable always? As I'm trying to solve it I always get stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**e** is the (column) vector of ones.

The Linear Programming problem you have provided is solvable, and has optimal objective value of 5.